# Why 'Double' wrapper class in Java can't be assigned to a float value whereas 'double' primitive type does?

Tags: java

Why is it a problem to assign a 'Double' wrapper class variable to a float value whereas assigning a 'double' primitive variable to a float value is fine?

```
double dVal5 = 1.4f;  // Works fine
Double dVal4 = 1.4f;  // Error: incompatible types: float cannot be converted to java.lang.Double

float fVal6 = 1.4f;
Float fVal7 = 1.4f;

double dVal6 = fVal6;  // Works fine
Double dVal7 = fVal6;  // Error: incompatible types: float cannot be converted to java.lang.Double
Double dVal8 = fVal7;  // Error: incompatible types: float cannot be converted to java.lang.Double
```

Java 11.0.5 is being used

Answer (score 2):

A primitive value can only be assigned to its corresponding wrapper reference type (`float` to `Float`, `double` to `Double`, etc...).

If you wish to assign it to a different wrapper type, you should add casting:

```
Double dVal7 = (double) fVal6;
```